# How to keep sachet coffee fresh?

Tags: storage, instant

I got some sachet coffee from Turkey. They are instant. I want to keep it fresh once it has opened. How can I make sure that the coffee remains fresh after opening as sachet turn to unwrap while sitting in cupboard.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what sachet instant coffee from Turkey is. Is it instant coffee (just soluble coffee concentrate crystals), or some form of dried Turkish coffee containing the grounds? Is the purpose of the sachet just portion control (you dump the single serving contents in a cup of hot water), or the sachet is filter material you brew the coffee in and then remove it? The answer to your question will be totally different depending on those definitions. Also, how long will it take you to go through it (how long to you need to preserve freshness)?

Answer (score 1):

> They are instant

As in instant coffee? There is nothing to keep fresh, this has never been fresh. Instant coffee is made by freeze-drying already brewed coffee. Any volatile compounds that could be in the coffee are long gone already before you open the sachet.

If it's simply pre-ground coffee then I'm afraid you're out of luck too, even if the coffee was fresh when ground and packed, the immense increase in surface area compared to whole bean coffee means that no matter what you do, after a few hours or after a few days at the very latest, your coffee will taste stale.